# Ionic 3 Network from @ionic-native/network doesn't return connection status

Tags: ionic3, ionic-native

How to get info about internet connection in ionic 3 application ?

I intalled plugin:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information

$ npm install --save @ionic-native/network
```

and added `import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';` to app`s module as provider

Console doesn't show errors, 
I tested it on laptop with chrome.

**pages/home.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController, LoadingController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { RestProvider } from '../../providers/rest/rest';
    import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
    import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })

    export class HomePage {

      constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController, 
        public LoadingController: LoadingController, 
        private rest: RestProvider,
        public  network: Network, 
        public toast: ToastController,
        public alertCtrl: AlertController,

        ) {

          this.network.onConnect().subscribe(()=> {
           console.log('Connected Constructor');
          });

          this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(()=> {
            console.log('Disonnected Constructor');
          });

        }


      ionViewDidLoad() {

        this.network.onConnect().subscribe(()=> {
          console.log('Connected ionViewDidLoad');
        });

        this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(()=> {
          console.log('Disonnected ionViewDidLoad');
        });
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks !!!

It's true, I changed my code

```
constructor(public toast: ToastController, private network: Network) {
this.network.onConnect().subscribe(()=> {
  this.toast.create({
    message: "DDDD",
    duration:6000
  }).present();
});

this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(()=> {
  this.toast.create({
    message: "213123",
    duration:6000
  }).present();
});
}
```

and it work on device,

but now i have another problem,

how get connection status after running aplication?,

(now i get status after change connection)

Comment: Use my answer to comment and you can edit your original question so there aren't multiple answers. I will update my answer to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova Plugins don't work in the browser. You'll have to run the app on a device to test on. Also, if you use `this.network.type` you'll be able to see the type of network on a device, but on the console in the broswer you'll get the warning:

> Native: tried calling Network.type, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator.

Confirmation that you won't be able to use cordova plugins on the browser.